# Cannot load highcharts in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts to load a graph my coding is working correctly in firefox . But if i load it in chrome means graph is not loaded. it throws the following errors.

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
   at a.Chart.load (loadmap:3239)
   at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:30)
   at a.Chart.onload (highcharts.js:272)
   at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:271)
   at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:247)
   at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:246)
   at new a.Chart (highcharts.js:246)
   at Object.a.chart (highcharts.js:246)
   at _.Le.<anonymous> (loadmap:3230)
   at Object._.B.trigger (js:99)
```

And my coding is in below ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/frontend/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="public/frontend/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="public/assets/js/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/assets/js/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="public/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {

  var left = [[4,7],[9,2]];
  var right = [[2,2],[9,9]];

  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="container" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 350px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

   </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title:{
      text:''
    },

    tooltip: { enabled: false },

    exporting: { enabled: false },

    credits: {enabled: false},

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 1
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      max: 10,
      min: 1,
      tickInterval: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
      max: 11,
      min: 0,
      tickInterval: 1,

      plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        value: 5.5,
        width: 2
      }],
    },

    series: [{
      showInLegend: false,
      data: left
      },
      {
      showInLegend: false,
      data: right
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

​I am using this via laravel. if i am using this code as html means it's working. But in laravel it's not working

Comment: You should not blame on the browser, since [compatibility](https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility) is proven. There is not chart type? `chart:{type:pie}`, for example... Maybe?

Comment: can you show your html too?

Comment: Please check my question .@ramon

Comment: Your [graph is working](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/pwgpwX?editors=1010). The only thing I see (it may just be a wrong cut n'paste here, is the `$(document).ready` and the `left` and `right` vars misplaced.

Comment: can you please tell where to place that ?

Comment: @Nisanth if you are new to this (laravel with highcharts) the follow this [blog](http://justlaravel.com/visualization-data-highcharts-laravel/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/frontend/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="public/frontend/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="public/assets/js/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/assets/js/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="public/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 350px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var left = [[4,7],[9,2]];
    var right = [[2,2],[9,9]];

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title:{
      text:''
    },

    tooltip: { enabled: false },

    exporting: { enabled: false },

    credits: {enabled: false},

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 1
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      max: 10,
      min: 1,
      tickInterval: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
      max: 11,
      min: 0,
      tickInterval: 1,

      plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        value: 5.5,
        width: 2
      }],
    },

    series: [{
      showInLegend: false,
      data: left
      },
      {
      showInLegend: false,
      data: right
      },
    ],
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. i will check this